# Is there a way to see which process invoked a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, process, logs, aix, audit

Is there a possibility so see from some unix log file what process have invoked a bash/ksh shell script or is this shell script invoked manually from command line? So is there some log file which stores this kind of history automatically?

Comment: Is the process still running? You could check its parent PID

Comment: No, process is not running.

Comment: You may want ask the users that were logged in at the time (see the output of `last`) or check their shell history files.

Comment: I don't know about AIX specifically, but this would be far more detailed logging than is typical. If you could modify the script, it would be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have [audit logging](http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-security_sd_draft/cha.audit.comp.html) enabled there isn't typically any way to see a log of what scripts were executed postmortem.

If it was a script that was executed from a a scheduler such as `cron` and/or `at` then these will show up in various log files under `/var/log`, in different log files depending on which Linux distro you're using.

#### References

- [auditd man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd)

Comment: Linux's audit facilities won't help under [tag:aix].

Comment: The details about "audit logging" are invalid since, as @Gilles pointed out, the question is about [tag:AIX] not [tag:linux]

Comment: @MaxVernon - correct, I'll delete this.